# Connecting an InputStream to an OutputStream

Tags: java, pipe, inputstream, outputstream

I have a Runnable class with input and output streams for read/write.
I want to create two thread of this Runnable and connect one's InputStream to other's OutputStream.

this is what I use:

```
PipedInputStream pin = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream pout = new PipedOutputStream(pin);
r1.setInputStream(pin);
r2.setOutputStream(pout);
```

is there any better solution?

Comment: What exactly do these two `Runnable` objects do? We can't give you better solutions without a better description of the problem.

Comment: they repeat this sequence : readline-process-writeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `java.nio.channels.Pipe`, another way of data connection between two threads.